# Spatial raster data interpolation in Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, interpolation

I have calculated the monthly ET from the 8-day MODIS data:

```
// Region of interest
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26, -24, 29, -27]);
// Calculate monthly MODIS
    var monthly_sum_MODIS = ee.List.sequence(0, 1*179).map(function(n){
    var start6 = ee.Date('2002-01-01').advance(n,'month');
    var end6 = start6.advance(1,'month');
    return ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2')
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterDate(start6,end6)
      .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
      .sum().multiply(0.1) //correction factor
      .select('ET','PET')
      .set('system:time_start',start6.millis());
    });
    //
    
    var collection_ET = ee.ImageCollection(monthly_sum_MODIS)
        .select('ET','PET');
```

The created dataset includes gaps or 'masked' areas.

How can I fill these gaps through interpolation in Google Earth Engine?
I don't understand what the x and y components are for ee.Image.interpolate as I though to map that across image collection.

Comment: Can you share your ROI or an area where these gaps are?

Comment: Yes sorry - var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26, -24, 29, -27]);

Answer (score 1):

Following lines are an extended version of your code where, it is added the mean of Image Collection.

```
// Region of interest
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26, -24, 29, -27]);

Map.setOptions("SATELLITE");
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point (28.0328, -26.1372), 9);
//Map.addLayer(roi);

// Calculate monthly MODIS
    var monthly_sum_MODIS = ee.List.sequence(0, 1*179).map(function(n){
    var start6 = ee.Date('2002-01-01').advance(n,'month');
    var end6 = start6.advance(1,'month');
    return ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2')
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterDate(start6,end6)
      .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
      .sum().multiply(0.1) //correction factor
      .select('ET','PET')
      .set('system:time_start',start6.millis());
    });
    //
    
    var collection_ET = ee.ImageCollection(monthly_sum_MODIS)
        .select('ET','PET');
        
    var mean = collection_ET.mean();
    
    var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                         "bands":["ET"],
                         "min":13.673595505617971,
                         "max":42.695,
                         "palette":["f0ff1e","f78d08","f71d06","110cff"]};
    
    Map.addLayer(mean, imageVisParam, 'mean');
```

After running above code, it can be observed in following picture that these "gaps" are "historical" (masked areas) and they delimit populated areas as Pretoria and Johannesburg. I think that in these places it makes no sense to interpolate ET or EPT values because ET is a function of vegetation cover, root, and soil; practically very reduced in these referred areas. Also, if it did, there are no pixels in those areas, for whatever image, to perform the interpolation task.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this insight. It is really helpful and really appreciate you taking the time. Blessed wishes :)